# ABCPDF and ABCChrome width isnt automated like Gecko Engine

Tags: abcpdf

I have been using `Gecko` engine for ABCPDF reports where the `BrowserWidth` is set to 0 where it will take the actual browser width of the page.  I would like to switch to `ABCChrome` but the width works a little differently.  Right now if you dont set a `BrowserWidth` the page looks larger in PDF format then the actual HTML version unlike the `Gecko` version.  If I set the `BrowserWidth` explicitly to 776, it looks exactly like Gecko.

My question is, is there not an automated way to use the actual webpage width, specifically for letter size like `Gecko` did? I would have to manually set the width for every report with `ABCChrome`.

**Gecko**

```
 doc.HtmlOptions.BrowserWidth = 776;
```

**ABCChrome**

```
 doc.HtmlOptions.BrowserWidth = 776;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was this flag being set to false that caused ABCChrome width issues.

```
doc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = false;
```